# inequality between two increasing sequences

Tags: inequality

I'm looking to answer the following question:

*There are given two increasing sequences*
$$a_n : 0.001; 0.004; 0.009; ... $$
$$b_n : 100; 300; 500; ... $$

*Can the 1st sequence catch up with the 2nd(that is, can the inequality $a_n > b_n$ be satisfied for some $n$)*

Looking at the 2 sequences I suspect that $a_n$ will surpass $b_n$ for some n as the intervals for a_n are growing.

How would I describe the situation in mathematical notation? In other words, I can see the answer to the question but I don't know how to write it down mathematically.

Comment: You need to define the sequences not just give the first three terms

Comment: My guess is that $a_n = 10^{-3} n^2$ while $b_n = 100 (2n-1)$.  If so, $a_n - b_n$ is a quadratic...

Comment: @BenW that was the way it was given in the question and I wasn't sure what you meant by define the sequences but RobertIsrael has given the answer. just define the sequences in that way and then solve for $a_n - b_n > 0$. At least I think that will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

for $n\ge 1$,

$$a_n=0.001\times n^2$$

$$b_n=-100+200n.$$

Comment: yes, I have it now. Thanks for the tip!